# angular 2 truncate length of the item

Tags: angular

In my template I am display some values like

```
<ion-card-content>
<chart *ngIf='item.isPublic' type="StockChart" [options]="options"></chart>
<ion-card-title>{{item.msg}}</ion-card-title>
<p class="card-text">{{item.time}}</p>
<p  class="card-text">{{item.agenda}}</p>
</ion-card-content>
```

right now to control the length of values like item.agenda I have to do it in the component class.

Is there a way to display first say 20 char of item.agenda by applying some expression in the template itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html).

> {{item.agenda | slice:0:20}}